# How to convert datetime to first Sunday of the week in R

Tags: r, datetime, data-conversion

**Goal**: Convert a date object to a date that is the Sunday of the week; they should still function as a date object

For example, today would convert to `2016-10-16`, tomorrow would convert to the same.

**Sample data:**

```
library(lubridate)
dt <- Sys.Date()-days(1:20)

"2016-10-17" "2016-10-16" "2016-10-15" "2016-10-14" "2016-10-13" "2016-10-12" "2016-10-11"
"2016-10-10" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-08" "2016-10-07" "2016-10-06" "2016-10-05"
"2016-10-04" "2016-10-03" "2016-10-02"
```

**Expected output:**

```
"2016-10-16" "2016-10-16" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09"
"2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02"
"2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02"
```

I've tried playing with `lubridate`, `zoo` and `xts` packages and `strptime`, but nothing quite serves the need.  The function `yearweek`  in MySQL does just what I want (note: package `sqldf` doesn't have that function).

<sup>This seems like something that would already have an answer, but had no luck with the search; C++, javascript, and Ruby, but nothing in R.</sup>

Comment: Have you checked `floor_date(dt, "week")`?

Comment: `dt - ((lubridate::wday(dt) + 5) %% 7 + 1)`

Comment: "first Sunday of the week"..?

Comment: @lukeA That is a very handy function, any way to choose which day the floor is set to?

Comment: @bigreddmachine  Feel free to use the edit feature, I have come to appreciate that weeks have one Sunday.

Comment: @Minnow :) I thought I might be missing something. Sorry if I came across as rude. I was also on the mobile app, and am not totally sure how to edit there!

Comment: @bigreddmachine My typo, my fault.  No worries!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another solution from start to finish -- no need for lubridate at any step along the way:

```
R> dt <- Sys.Date() - 1:20
R> newdt <- dt - as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday
R> data.frame(dt, newdt)
           dt      newdt
1  2016-10-16 2016-10-16
2  2016-10-15 2016-10-09
3  2016-10-14 2016-10-09
4  2016-10-13 2016-10-09
5  2016-10-12 2016-10-09
6  2016-10-11 2016-10-09
7  2016-10-10 2016-10-09
8  2016-10-09 2016-10-09
9  2016-10-08 2016-10-02
10 2016-10-07 2016-10-02
11 2016-10-06 2016-10-02
12 2016-10-05 2016-10-02
13 2016-10-04 2016-10-02
14 2016-10-03 2016-10-02
15 2016-10-02 2016-10-02
16 2016-10-01 2016-09-25
17 2016-09-30 2016-09-25
18 2016-09-29 2016-09-25
19 2016-09-28 2016-09-25
20 2016-09-27 2016-09-25
R>
```

Comment: Good to be reminded that `POSIXlt` objects yield the integer and numeric values that I'm usually wanting.

Comment: Also very useful and even more succint.  I like that this is essentially a single call.  For the record this is ~10x faster than @JoshO'Brien 's strftime solution.

Comment: Thanks for timing that. I had the same thought -- if in doubt, avoid textual representation and reparsing.

Answer (score 5):

No need for **lubridate** here. You can instead just do something like the following.

```
## `%w` returns weekday as number between 0 and 6, with 0 meaning "Sunday"  
dt - as.numeric(strftime(dt, format="%w"))
#  [1] "2016-10-16" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09"
#  [6] "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02"
# [11] "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02"
# [16] "2016-09-25" "2016-09-25" "2016-09-25" "2016-09-25" "2016-09-25"
```

Comment: I have something similar using a numeric adjustment by subtracting `POSIXlt`'s `wday` field.

Answer (score 1):

In the [[quickref zoo vignette]](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf) there is a one line function `nextfri` that gives the next Friday.  We can readily modify it -- replace 5 for Friday with 0 for Sunday and replace `ceiling` with `floor` to get last rather than next.  Using the input shown in the question (and reproducibly shown in the Note at the end) we get the following.  Note that the zoo package must be loaded for this to work.

```
library(zoo)
lastsun <- function(x) 7 * floor(as.numeric(x-0+4) / 7) + as.Date(0-4)

lastsun(x)
```

giving:

```
 [1] "2016-10-16" "2016-10-16" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09"
 [6] "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-02"
[11] "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-02"
[16] "2016-10-02"
```

or simplifying further we get to this which does *not require that zoo be loaded* and gives the same output:

```
lastsun2 <- function(x) x - as.numeric(x+4) %% 7  
lastsun2(x)
```

**Note:** Input `x` used is:

```
x <- as.Date(c("2016-10-17", "2016-10-16", "2016-10-15", "2016-10-14", "2016-10-13", 
  "2016-10-12", "2016-10-11", "2016-10-10", "2016-10-09", "2016-10-08", "2016-10-07", 
  "2016-10-06", "2016-10-05", "2016-10-04", "2016-10-03", "2016-10-02"))
```